# A difficult case of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wish to find a closed form for the series below

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{2k}r^k\cos(kx) $ with $ |r|<1 $

I already have a closed form for

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty kr^k\cos(kx) $

So i wonder if there is a way to find the closed form for the first series with the aid of the second.

Comment: Is it really $k^{2k}$, or just $k^2$? In the former case, the series looks divergent, since $k^{2k}r^k \rightarrow \infty$ for each $r > 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes it is $ k^{2k} $ and $ r $  is imaginary with $ |r|<1 $.

Comment: Even so, $|k^{2k}r^k| \rightarrow \infty$ for any complex number $r \neq 0$, no?

Comment: Ok, what if the series does not go to infinity but some number $ N $ is it possible to approximate the result with the last term i,e for $ k=N $?